# How to compute whether the mean of a non-random sub-sample is statistically different from the mean of the sample?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, mean, sample

I have a variable called "obs" and from this variable I generated a new variable called "obs_sub" by excluding all observations for which a dummy variable is equal to one. Now what I want to know is if I remove these observations whether the mean of the sub-sample is equal to the mean of the sample. This is my null hypothesis.

I could run a regression of $E[obs|d] = \alpha + \beta \cdot d$, but the regression with the dummy $(d)$ will only tell me whether the coefficient on the dummy is statistically significant from zero. It will not tell me whether the data are unlikely given $E[obs|d=1] = E[obs]$ or is the null hypothesis $\beta=0$ the same as the null hypothesis as $E[obs|d=1] = E[obs]$?

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: differences in *sample* means can be assessed by inspection. No need for tests.

Comment: Thanks Glen_b, I realize that, but what I want to know in addition is whether those differences are statistically significant. If there is say a five point differences and this differences is not statistically significant and the power of the test is high, then the fact that the null hypothesis is not rejected helps a bit to argue that there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

A better null hypothesis (and substantively equivalent) is to see whether the subsample's mean is equal to the mean of all the *other* cases. That is, divide the sample into two mutually exclusive subsamples. Then you can run a t-test between them (or some nonparametric variation, if need be).

If this variation of the null isn't workable, could you say why not?

And, if it isn't, you could do a permutation test

Comment: Thanks for your answer Peter, I see now also that I made a mistake in writing down the mathematical expression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Peter, I see now also that I made a mistake in writing down the mathematical expression.

The hypothesis should be that the conditional mean is equal to the unconditional mean. $E[obs|d=1] = E[obs]$ 

What you suggest would rightly be the answer to what I wrote when I said $E[obs|d=1] = E[obs|d=0]$ as this would be comparing two conditional means or two sub-samples.

Comment: I am not sure though that the solution offered would work. For we can write $E[obs] = (1-w) \cdot E[obs|d=1] + w \cdot E[obs|d=0]$ for the value of the unconditional mean, and my guess is that it depends on $w$ whether both are substantively equivalent. I don't know however.